# Problems with Android Auto App Verification

Tags: android, google-play, android-auto

I have noticed that, when I do a staged rollout of an app with Android-Auto support, the app gets re-evaluated every time I change the percentage of users the app is made available to.  The evaluation is also tremendously inconsistent, with the app passing about 80% of the time, and failing, with meaningless messages such as "Your app does not perform all functions properly or as expected from a user perspective."  If this is not the final, 100% roll out, there is no problem, as the review will likely be different on the next iteration.  However, if the rejection happens on the final roll-out, it blocks the app for all users (not just the < 1% that use Android Auto.)

This is largely a rant about Google's flawed evaluation mechanism, but I would like to know if anyone has a way to get the APK evaluated once, so that you can complete the rollout based on a final review, or a way to trigger a new review - changing the config in some trivial way and hitting submit again?  Any ways to work through this flawed process would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, as you might know the app-review is a manual process and each reviewer would have a slightly different point of view, so you might want to cross check with the guild line and leave them notes to help them understand your app. Also for android auto, google is playing it save with all the regulations; so no auto reviews on auto app and I think they are reviewing as much as they can so that people can't blame on android auto when they crash into something.

Comment: Thanks - I just wish they would review each APK once and give you an answer, instead of re-reviewing it every time you extend the roll-out and changing their response.  The responses tend to be nonsense, too - I got a "doesn't have night mode" on an audio app where the whole UI is done by Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has become clear to us that the Android Auto approval process is too arbitrary and opaque for us to include it in an ordinary release cycle.  The best solution was to remove Android Auto support from our application - we could not allow unpredictable failed reviews to disrupt our release cycle, and the reviews did not provide any useful feedback for remedying any app deficiencies - indeed, they seemed to have little to do with our application at all.  If Android Auto becomes a significant marketplace presence in the future, we may explore releasing a separate application for Android Auto alone.  For now, it seems as though it is not worth the harm caused to other users by interrupting our release cycle.